# iOS Obj-C double to NaN in one hop on stack trace

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a valid double that is turning into `NaN` as it is passed to a method. I have no idea how this is happening, but have a look at this:

[image: Valid Double]
Notice `posInSeconds` is a double with a valid numerical value.

One step up on the stack trace
[image: NaN]

I'm not an Obj-C expert by any means, but this makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: What does it show if you type `print time` in the debugger? Sometimes the variables view shows incorrect values.

Comment: What is the warning on the line above (the method declaration)? Is there a mismatched parameter type in the .h file?

Comment: @Kevin yeah there was a mismatched type, I am in the middle of refactoring and haven't buttoned everything up yet. That was the problem. Submit this in an answer so that you can get your rep.

Comment: Learn to have a zero tolerance policy on warnings. They almost always indicate something that is going to malefaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mismatch in the types between the header and implementation. 
The compiler is passing one type (possibly an implicit cast to int), and reinterprets the same bits as something else (a double) on the other side.